# rust-lldb pretty-printing arrays

Tags: rust, lldb

I noticed that `rust-lldb` pretty-prints arrays differently depending on context:

```
   1    fn init(array: &mut[i32; 9]) {
   2      array[4] = 333;
-> 3    }
   4    
   5    fn main() {
   6      let mut array: [i32; 9] = [18; 9];
   7      init(&mut array);
(lldb) p array[0]
(int[9]) {
  [0] = 18
  [1] = 18
  [2] = 18
  [3] = 18
  [4] = 333
  [5] = 18
  [6] = 18
  [7] = 18
  [8] = 18
}
```

When I step out of `init` I get a different print format:

```
   4    
   5    fn main() {
   6      let mut array: [i32; 9] = [18; 9];
-> 7      init(&mut array);
   8      println!("{}", array[4]);
   9    }
Target 0: (main) stopped.
(lldb) p array[0]
(int) 18
(lldb) ### x/9u &array <--- this works fine
```

How come the print format changes between those contexts?

```rust
// main.rs

fn init(array: &mut[i32; 9]) {
  array[4] = 333;
}

fn main() {
  let mut array: [i32; 9] = [18; 9];
  init(&mut array);
  println!("{}", array[4]);
}
```

Compiled and run with:

```bash
$ rustc -g main.rs
$ rust-lldb --source ./commands.dbg ./main
```

and here are the exact commands:

```bash
# commands.dbg

b main.rs:3
run
p array[0]
next
p array[0]
### x/9u &array <--- this works fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLDB sees things in a C-centric way.

The difference between these cases are the types `array` is a `&mut [i32; 9]` at your breakpoint in `init`, but its `[i32; 9]` in at the next step in `main()`. Under the hood a `&mut` reference is just a pointer and LLDB says as such when just looking at `p array`:

```
// in init()
(lldb) p array
(int (*)[9]) $2 = 0x00007fffffffdba4

// in main()
(lldb) p array
(int [9]) $5 = {
  [0] = 18
  [1] = 18
  [2] = 18
  [3] = 18
  [4] = 333
  ...
```

Note the difference between `int (*)[9]` (a pointer to `int` array) and `int [9]` (an `int` array).

So when you are printing `array[0]`, they do different things. In `init()` you are simply dereferencing the reference and thus printing the array itself (since that is how `[0]` works in C), whereas in `main()` you are simply accessing the first element of the array:

```
// in init()
(lldb) p array[0]
(int [9]) $0 = {
  [0] = 18
  [1] = 18
  [2] = 18
  [3] = 18
  [4] = 333
  ...

// in main()
(lldb) p array[0]
(int) $6 = 18
```

Your `x/9u &array` in `main()` is essentially giving you the same as the simple `p array` just with a lot more verbosity.

---

So if you want to display the array and the variable is a reference use `*` to dereference it:

```
(lldb) p *array
(int [9]) $10 = {
  [0] = 18
  [1] = 18
  [2] = 18
  [3] = 18
  [4] = 333
```